# Android google map application crash calling from one activity through intent

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using [Google MapView Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview) . I am calling this Map Activity by clicking button, but i'm getting FATAL EXCEPTION, plz help me

Here is my **Activity class** :

```
public class AddLocationMap extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
}
```

}

AND the xml file is just like this -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**Logcat :** This is LogCat output

```
  02-04 17:06:18.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  02-04 17:06:18.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2718): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
  02-04 17:06:18.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2718):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
  02-04 17:06:18.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2718):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link you provided **Google Maps Android v1 API (Deprecated)**

Quoting

> Note: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially
>   deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th,
>   2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this
>   version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1.
>   However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and
>   new developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.

Switch to api v2.

Follow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: @SajatApplexusTechnologies follow the link in my post

Comment: yes follow all the steps in the docs ( the link i posted ) and it will surely workk

Comment: @SajatApplexusTechnologies wow you swithed to api v2 so quickly. Take some time to read the docs or else you will end up in more errors

Comment: @SajatApplexusTechnologies you need google play services to be referenced in your android project. as i said pls take time to read the docs full and then code

Comment: @SajatApplexusTechnologies Tell me how you referenced google play services?

Comment: Hi Raghunandan, google-play-services_libs , i imported this & using as a library

Comment: @SajatApplexusTechnologies if so you won't see that excpetion in stacktrace. that means you are doing it wrong

Comment: Hi Raghu, getting messageg "This app won't work unless you update google play services", so again h'v to update !!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46758/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-saj-at-applexus-technologies)